# how to write a small image popup using java script?

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I have a product page in my website and there are 12 products and each product have a unique photo and description table. and I need a small popup model to show the description table when an user click the product photo. how can i do the task? this is my product page's code

```
 <!--1-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>

<!--2-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>

<!--3-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>


<!--4-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>

<!--5-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>

<!--6-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>

<!--7-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>

<!--8-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>

<!--9-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>

<!--10-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>

<!--11-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div>

<!--12-->
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="image">
<p>
<img style="width: 100%; border-radius: 60px 20px 60px 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; border: 7px solid #3366ff;"  src="http://steelrich.com/SR/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deformed_steel_bar_for_construction_8537_1.jpg" />

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: is this your static product page or you will gonna loop through the product array and display product by looping each product section. Actually I like to use boostrap modal for popups but you you are using static product page then you need to write modal code for every product. First see the boostrap modal `http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp ` and see if you can get some idea that how you gonna call that modal dynamically.

Comment: ya my product page is static and I already went through the link you provided.. what is the easy way to achieve my task?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Although I second Shailesh Singh's bootstrap model idea.

This way doesn't require use of bootstrap, making it one full step easier.

Answer (score 0):

A concept: Create a div (your popup) with dispay hidden and give each photo an unique id or attribute. Add an on click event listener on the photo div classes. When clicking a photo, get the clicked attribute or Id and change the content of your hidden popup div to your description table. Then set the display of the popup to block.